# What's the best way to preserve an exit code or assign it to a variable with Bash?

Tags: bash, exit-code

I'm trying to save the exit code from running `psql` in a shell script. Assuming the `psql` command right before this snippet was bad, I'm expecting this snippet to return anything but `1`, which it initially does. But when I assign it to `exitcode` and then `echo` it, the returned value is a `0`...

```
$ echo $?
    1
$ exitcode=$?
$ echo 'simply'
    simply
$ #echo $?
    0
$ #echo 'coding'
    coding
$ echo $exitcode
    0
```

I'm trying to get the variable `exitcode` to print or echo 1 like the first line does. How do I exactly do this?

Comment: Exit Code from `psql` & `OS` are different. What are you trying here

Comment: Assign to `exitcode` *before* you do `echo $?`. The way you did it, you saved the exit code of `echo`, not `psql`.

Comment: The exit code($?) of your second line is not from psql but your first line `echo $?`

Comment: Does `$?` get updated with every command run in bash? So if I arrange the commands to `psql; exitcode=$?;` then does `$?` and `exitcode` get updated to the result of running the command `exitcode=$?`

Comment: `exitcode` is not tied to `$?` for the rest of the session; it is simply assigned the current value of `$?` and does not change when `$?` changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you print `$?` the second time, it's *not* the exit code of the previous command.
You need to assign `$?` to `exitcode` immediately before running any other command.

i.e.

```
$ psql
$ echo $?
    1
$ exitcode=$?
```

should be

```
$ psql
$ exitcode=$?
```

in order to preserve the exit code of `psql`.

Comment: Thanks. If I run `psql; exitcode=$?; echo $exitcode; echo $exitcode;`, then I get `1` then `0`. I forget the terminology for when this happens with variable assignment, but is this normal?

Comment: What you observed is expected.

Comment: No it's not. `$exitcode` changing value spontaneously is absolutely unexpected. That's called *lazy evaluation*, and bash does not have it. There's no way `echo $exitcode; echo $exitcode;` could produce `1` then `0`.

Comment: Actually, I had a commented line between the two `echo` statements and removed it, so they're now returning the same result. Mistake on my part for assuming the commented lines would not affect the value of `exitcode`. Would love to hear an explanation on that behavior though, since I'm fairly inexperienced with Bash